# Else statement not readjusting height and width of img after If statement adjusts the img

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

When the user scrolls more than 50px down the viewport, my if statement adjusts a bunch of elements in the header. Once the user scrolls back to less than 50px, it readjusts back to normal with an else statement. Currently, everything functions fine besides my img height and width within the else statement. For some reason, the code doesn't bounce back to 60px in height after shifting to 30px in the if/else statement. Please let me know what you think is wrong with the else statement. I assume is has something to do with catching images specifically.

HTML

```
<img class="header-logo-img header-logo-img-illustration" id="header-logo-img-illustration" src="../imgs/NoahPointingIllustration.png" alt="logo illustration" height="60" width="60">
```

CSS

```
// When the user scrolls down 50px from the top of the page, resize the header
    $(document).ready(function () {
      window.onscroll = function() {
        dynamicHeaderOnScroll()
      };
    
      function dynamicHeaderOnScroll() {
        if (document.body.scrollTop > 50 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50) {
          document.getElementById("header-wrapper").style.maxWidth = "100%";
          document.getElementById("header").style.paddingTop = "10px";
          document.getElementById("header").style.paddingBottom = "0.4em";
          // Reposition "close hamburger menu" icon
          document.getElementById("closebtn").style.margin = "-43px 0 0 0";
          document.getElementById("header-logo-img-illustration").style.height = "30px";
          document.getElementById("header-logo-img-illustration").style.width = "30px";
        } else {
          document.getElementById("header-wrapper").style.maxWidth = "900px";
          document.getElementById("header").style.paddingTop = "55px";
          document.getElementById("header").style.paddingBottom = "0.25em";
          document.getElementById("header-homepage").style.paddingBottom = "1em";
          // Reposition "close hamburger menu" icon
          document.getElementById("closebtn").style.margin = "0";
          document.getElementById("header-logo-img-illustration").style.height = "60px"; // ISSUE HERE
          document.getElementById("header-logo-img-illustration").style.width = "60px"; // ISSUE HERE
        };
      };
```

Large image in header on page load:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJxYm.png

Img shrunk when scrolled down:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGywm.png

Img remains shrunk when scrolled back up and is supposed to go back to default like the first image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDMHo.png

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you inspect the element, what do you see the width & height set to? Are there any other Class styles that might be cascading to this element? Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your devtools console! - If your code crashes before resizing the image, it - well - won't resize the image.

[image: error screenshot]

You can see here that the code crashes due to the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')
    at dynamicHeaderOnScroll (main.js:144)
    at window.onscroll (main.js:130)
```

...which happens in this line:

```js
document.getElementById("header-homepage").style.paddingBottom = "1em";
```

So, it complains about not being able to read properties, in particular `style`, from the value `null`. From that follows that `document.getElementById("header-homepage")` must have returned `null` so that you essentially did `null.style.paddingBottom`, hence the error. And why is that so? Because there is no element with ID `header-homepage` on your page.

---

Side note: It would make a lot more sense to have those styles in CSS depending on a class.

For example, you can use a class `is-scrolled` on the `<body>` tag - and all your JS code would need to do then is `document.body.classList.add('is-scrolled')` (and `remove`, of course).

You would then define the rules in your stylesheet such as this:

```css
body.is-scrolled #closebtn {
  margin: -43px 0 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! Does this mean that when called in JS, IDs will create errors if not found and classes will not?

Comment: I tried just calling the class name with getElementsByClassName() but this never functions. I haven't figured out why so I just used IDs, not knowing I could run into errors if they aren't used on all pages. Do you have insight into how to use getElementsByClassName()?

Comment: @Neg any selection of a element that does not exist will return `null`, Class or ID. Using Classes with your elements allows you to assign styling without a lot of extra code. Instead of having 3 or 4 lines of code each to add or remove styles, just add or remove a Class name and the browser will render it.